# How can i start a video downloaded from parse in MPMoviePlayerController

Tags: xcode, parse-platform, ios8, mpmovieplayer, pffile

How can i play a video using MPMoviePlayerController downloaded from parse saved as PFFile?
I downloaded the video file with this code:

```
    var query = PFQuery(className:"Video")
    query.whereKey("Nome", equalTo:"prova")
    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
        (objects: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

        if error == nil {
            // The find succeeded.
            println("Successfully retrieved \(objects!.count) scores.")
            if let objects = objects as? [PFObject] {
                for object in objects {
                    var imageFile:PFFile =object.objectForKey("Video")
                    imageFile.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock {
                        (imageData: NSData?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

                     ?????????????   
                    }

            }
        } else {
            println("Error: \(error!) \(error!.userInfo!)")
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can save that data temporary in document directory and play video from       
`NSString *strLocation = [@"~/Documents/downloadedFile.mov" stringByExpandingTildeInPath];
// Use Your Downloaded Data
[data writeToFile:strLocation atomically:YES];
// Pass URL of that saved file in Player
MPMoviePlayerController *player = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:strLocation]];`

Hope this helps you.